# Merge two Observables and pass into dataSource as a single Observable for Angular material table

Tags: html, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I am fairly new to Web development and am stuck on this problem from past some days, Would appreciate a heck lot if the community could help me out here

I want to merge two observables coming out of firebase database, I want to join them concurrently i.e
3 rows of the first observable to be mapped with the three rows from the other observable. I want to use this observable into my dataSource for Angular Mat Table. and extract fields from both the observable here

This is the Component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductService } from 'src/app/product.service';
import { Observable, observable } from 'rxjs';
import "rxjs/add/observable/zip";
import "rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-products',
  templateUrl: './admin-products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-products.component.css']
})
export class AdminProductsComponent implements OnInit {
  products$:Observable<any[]>
  productsKey$:Observable<any[]>
  finalProduct$
  list:[]

  constructor(private productService:ProductService) {
    this.products$ = this.productService.getAll().valueChanges();

    this.productsKey$ = this.productService.getAll().snapshotChanges();


    //this.finalProduct$ = (this.products$).pipe(merge(this.productsKey$));

  }

   displayedColumns = ['title','price','edit'];
  // dataSource = this.products$

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }



}
```

This is the service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductService {

  constructor(private db:AngularFireDatabase) { }

  create(product){
 console.log(product)
   return this.db.list('/products').push(product);

  }

  getAll(){
    return this.db.list('/products')
  }
}
```

this is the final HTML markup

```
<p style="padding: 50px;">
    <button mat-flat-button color="primary" routerLink="/admin/products/new" > Add New Product</button>
</p>




<mat-table  [dataSource]="finalProduct$ | async" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="title">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Title </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element.title }} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="price">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Price </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.price}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="edit">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>  </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element | json}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>


    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
```

The first Observable **products$** has data in this format

```
{category: "bread", imageUrl: "https://pixabay.com/photos/bread-food-isolated-croissant-loaf-4592483/", price: 50, title: "Freshly Baked Bread"}
```

the Second observable **productsKey$** has data in this format

```
{payload: DataSnapshot, type: "value", prevKey: null, key: "-M9HwZl_WYfgTchxanrb"}
```

I wish to extract the Price, title and key value from these observables and display them in a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I would suggest using `zip` which does exactly what you want, i.e merge 2 observables.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  zip(this.products$, this.productsKey$).pipe(
    map(reponse => { return {...reponse[0], ...response[1]}})
  ).subscribe(
    reponse => {
      this.dataSource = reponse;
    });
```

You can also use `combineLatest` as [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6513921/michael-d) suggested with slight modifications. Change `map(reponse => [...reponse[0], ...response[1]])` to `map(reponse => { return {...reponse[0], ...response[1]}})`

Comment: HI KoosKoos, Thankyou so much. This worked like a charm

Comment: Thanks, @mohitnirwan. Glad, I was able to help :)

Answer (score 0):

If the observables are independent of each other you could use RxJS [`combineLatest()`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/combineLatest) function to combine multiple observables.

```js
displayedColumns = ['title', 'price', 'edit'];

constructor(private productService: ProductService) {
  this.products$ = this.productService.getAll().valueChanges();
  this.productsKey$ = this.productService.getAll().snapshotChanges();
}

ngOnInit(): void {
  combineLatest(this.products$, this.productsKey$).pipe(
    take(1),     // <-- remove it if the data stream needs to persist
    map(reponse => [...reponse[0], ...response[1]])
  ).subscribe(
    reponse => {
      this.dataSource = reponse;
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer so quickly, it seems to be working but a slight hiccup. the output ain't the desired one. https://imgur.com/oAjlYjK . Could you help me in realigning the output into the same rows and not in new ones @michael-d

Comment: @mohitnirwan: The issue is in this line: `reponse => [...reponse[0], ...response[1]]`. The object structure should be modified to match your requirement.

Comment: Yes, Figured that out. Thankyou so much